# Laravel, error de conexión a localhost

Tags: php, laravel

Me esta surgiendo un problema a la hora de visualizar en la web mi proyecto `laravel`.

Si yo escribo en la barra de direcciones, `http://localimagenes/imagenes`,
si que logra entrar:

```
{"datos":[{"id":1,"imagen":"http:\/\/fotosparafondodepantalla.net\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/07\/fotos-para-fondo-de-pantalla-para-celular-thor.jpg","imagen_redimensionada":"http:\/\/fotosparafondodepantalla.net\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/07\/fotos-para-fondo-de-pantalla-para-celular-thor.jpg","categorias_id":1}]}
```

Pero si escribo mi ip: http://192.168.1.2/imagenes

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. 1/1
>   NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:
>
> ```
> in RouteCollection.php line 145
> at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 729
> at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 652
> at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
> at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
> at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
> at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
> at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
> at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
> at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
> at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
> at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
> at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 100
> at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
> at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
> at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 52
> ```

Así es como tengo configurado el localhost:

Archivo Vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ImagenesApi/public"
    ServerName localimagenes
</VirtualHost>
```

Archivo host:

```
127.0.0.1    localimagenes
```

Laravel:
routes.php:

```
    <?php
    Route::resource('imagenes', 'ImagenesController', ['only' => ['index','show','destroy']]);

    Route::resource('categorias','CategoriasController',['except' => ['edit','create']]);

    Route::resource('categorias.imagenes','CategoriasImagenesController', ['except' => 'show','edit','create']);
```

No sé si os pueden hacer falta mas datos, me he quedado  estancado y no sé como solucionarlo os agradeceria una ayuda, gracias!!

Comment: Perdon y si entras nomas a http://192.168.1.2

Comment: Ya que al entrar `http://192.168.1.2/imagenes` no lo encontrara debido a que no estan en la rutas de tu proyecto, debido a que lo declaraste como `localhost`, entonces deberias entrar a `http://192.168.1.2`

Comment: Buenas, ¿te valió la respuesta? ¿Necesitas más información?

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo:

¿Para que quieres que se acceda por `IP`?

En cualquiera de los casos, seguramente el error sea que no estas permitiendo el acceso por `IP`. Ya que a Apache le dices que solo acepte peticiones que tengan la cabecera de `localimagenes`

Seguramente tu `VirtualHost` debería de ser:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ImagenesApi/public"
    ServerName  192.168.1.2
    ServerAlias localimagenes
</VirtualHost>
```

Prueba con eso y me comentas.